# Deserializing json array

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I'd like to deserialize a json string, but somehow i dont get the correct value :(
This is the input json string

```
{
  "files":[
    {"path":"/c/asd/input.txt","size":13},
    {"path":"/c/asd/input.txt","size":136},
    {"path":"/c/asd/input.txt","size":483},
    {"path":"/c/asd/input.txt","size":136}
  ],
  "md5sum":"bbd88df7b2d8c95f922ebf0d718b5687"
}
```

Created a class for it

```
public class Files
    {
    public string path { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    }
public class myObject
    {
    public List<Files> files { get; set; }
    public string md5sum { get; set; }
    }
```

And trying to use JavaScriptSerializer:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<myObject> obj = s.Deserialize<List<myObject>>(File.ReadAllText(json));
```

What am i doing wrong? obj count is zero. I need to use only the path value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is one root object, not a list. Try:

```
var obj = s.Deserialize<myObject>(File.ReadAllText(json));
```

Also, I'm assuming that `json` here is a path to a file, and not the json itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jss.Deserialize<myObject>(File.ReadAllText(json));
```

because you try deserialize a collection (List), but the s object is a not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your input json is not a list.Change
     `Deserialize<List<myObject>` to     `Deserialize<myObject>`